# How does Friend-or-Foe Q-learning intuitively work?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, terminology, game-theory, multi-agent-systems

I read about Q-Learning and was reading about multi-agent environments. I tried to read the paper [Friend-or-Foe Q-learning](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.589.8571&rep=rep1&type=pdf), but could not understand anything, except for a very vague idea.

What does [Friend-or-Foe Q-learning](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.589.8571&rep=rep1&type=pdf) mean? How does it work? Could someone please explain this expression or concept in a simple yet descriptive way that is easier to understand and that helps to get the correct intuition?

Comment: Hi Harris Pat and welcome to this community! We're glad to help if we can, but, please, **ask one question per post**. I've edited your post to leave only the first question. Please, ask the other 3 questions in their separate post.